# How to use stored procedure in GraphQL using HotChocolate

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am currently working on a legacy application which is built on the .NET framework and uses a MySQL database. We are migrating the application to GraphQL and .NET Core. We need to use the existing stored procedures. Because, the userid\DB-role is passed to the stored procedure to filter the data at the database level.

I have created a POC using Entity Framework for the GraphQL using hotchocolate. Since, I'm new to GraphQL and I don't know how to pass userid\DB-role along with the request or in resolvers, I am planning to use stored procedure method. Hence, need help on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define a resolver and execute the stored procedure how you like.

E.g.

```
services.AddGraphQLServer().AddQueryType<Query>();
```

```cs
public class Query 
{
    public async Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(
      [Service] AnyServiceFromTheSerivceProvider service,
      Guid id, 
      CancellationToken ct) => await service.GetUserByIdAsync(id, ct);
}
```